# Adding OpenCV 2.4.5 Library to Intellij Idea 12.1

Tags: android, opencv, intellij-idea

I want to use openCV in my android applications but I couldn't find a way to add opencv libraries in intellij Idea and use them.

How to use OpenCV4Android in Intellij Idea ??

Comment: Check it up! This topic helped me:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16412936/how-to-use-opencv-with-intellij-idea-12