# I need to install opencv and use it via java in Maven+IntelliJ (on Windows and macOS/OSX).

Tags: java, windows, macos, opencv, intellij-idea

I need to install opencv and use it via java in Maven+IntelliJ (on Windows and macOS/OSX). What is the "standard" or easy way?

Comment: Found Maven http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openpnp/opencv/2.4.13-0 but "import org.opencv.imgcodecs' was not resolved.

Comment: Found a good how-to: http://www.rmnd.net/install-and-use-opencv-3-0-on-mac-os-x-with-eclipse-java/ . It starts from downloading opencv...zip, which solves the problem of what version is installing.

Answer (score 4):

I googled extensively and did look at [How to use OpenCV with IntelliJ IDEA 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16412936/how-to-use-opencv-with-intellij-idea-12).
Here is what worked for me and it looks simple enough. Please comment if there is a "better" and/or "standard" way. Wish list: **I would like to be able to remove opencv easily from my computer if not needed anymore** (some of my laptops run out of disk space).

The following is done on macOS Sierra (10.12.1)

**Step1:** download and install opencv via command-line (i.e. Terminal on macOS/OSX): see http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html

UPDATE 17-Nov-2016: http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html

```
$ mkdir ~/dev/lib/opencv/github_opencv_161101
$ cd ~/dev/lib/opencv/github_opencv_161101
$ git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git
```

I used `~/dev/lib/opencv/github_opencv_161101` as my install directory, so I could remove it easily if needed, and to remind myself when I installed it.

**Step 2:** build. Note, the last command below `$ sudo make install` will copy all libs to `/usr/local`. However, I tried to install opencv via at least two other ways (via brew and http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html), so I am not sure which libraries are which in `/usr/local`.

```
$ cd opencv
$ mkdir release
$ cd release
$ cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local .. 
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

**Notes on used tools**: You also need JavaSDK installed. My `cmake` is

```
$ cmake -version
cmake version 3.6.2
```

If you do not have `cmake` installed, use `brew` (or install from http://brew.sh/ )

```
$ brew install cmake
```

You may also need to install [Command Line Tools not working - OS X El Capitan/ macOS-sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32893412/command-line-tools-not-working-os-x-el-capitan-macos-sierra) via

```
$ xcode-select --install
```

**Step 3:** Running `HelloCV.java` in IntelliJ. Start IntelliJ. Create New Project. Select Maven
[image]

Continue until you get
[image]
**Enable auto-import!**

Create new class HelloCV and type (from https://github.com/opencv-java/opencv-java-tutorials/blob/master/docs/source/02-first-java-application-with-opencv.rst):

```
public class HelloCV {
    public static void main(String[] args){
            System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
            Mat mat = Mat.eye(3, 3, CvType.CV_8UC1);
            System.out.println("mat = " + mat.dump());
    }
}
```

You should get something like:
[image]

Now, finally the payload ;-) Select File->Project Structure:
[image]

Select Libraries (or Global libraries), and add java library:
[image]

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/24853043/1006226: Navigate to `~/dev/lib/opencv/github_opencv_161101/opencv/release/bin` in my case, or `~/path_to_your_dir/opencv/release/bin`.
[image]

You can now compile and run your HelloCV.java:

```
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;

public class HelloCV {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
        Mat mat = Mat.eye(3, 3, CvType.CV_8UC1);
        System.out.println("mat = " + mat.dump());
    }
}
```

But you will get the following runtime error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java310 in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1864)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at org.dak.HelloCV.main(HelloCV.java:9)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Go back to Menu->File->Project Structure, select Libraries and add 
`~/dev/lib/opencv/github_opencv_161101/opencv/release/lib` in my case, or `~/path_to_your_dir/opencv/release/lib`

[image]
[image]

Now, you are linked to the native libs via JNI. Run HelloCV and you should get:

```
mat = [  1,   0,   0;
   0,   1,   0;
   0,   0,   1]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: This looks awfully complicated for just fetching opencv to build/run. The simplest way I found is to host the opencv on your own repo. Then copy it on each build with a maven plugin and load it via a relative path. I've written a short 2-part tutorial on how I did it: http://dindoffer.eu/2016/12/30/opencv-with-maven-part-1-create-your-own-maven-repo-wo-high-level-bullshit/